# Iterating over full text lines instead of characters

Tags: python, text, iteration

I noticed when I try to iterate over a file with lines such as 
"python"
"please" 
"work" 
I only get individual characters back, such as, 
"p"
"y"
"t"...

how could I get it to give me the full word? I've been trying a couple hours and can't find a method. I'm using the newest version of python. 
Edit: All the quotation marks are new lines.

Comment: I got infuriated and deleted what I had, essentially thought I had the code for the function I was trying to write, I tried storing each element as a substring, then appending it to the list I was trying to make but it didn't work. I'm sorry for not posting an effort though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over a file object:

```
for line in open('file'):
    for word in line.split():
        do_stuff(word)
```

See the docs for the details:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects

Comment: I edited my post to show what is actually happening. I know how to iterate over the characters of a line in the file, I just want the whole line itself though.

Comment: ...and i have updated my answer to match. ;-)

Comment: Is there any forum etiquette in dealing with a completed post?

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the words as a string, you can split the words by space using split function.

```
>>> "python please work".split(' ')
['python', 'please', 'work']
```

Comment: I was thinking that, but the words are on different lines. Essentially I want it to go to each line and take all the information as one string when I'm iterating, not as characters.

Comment: Can you copy and paste two or three lines of your code? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data in a single string which spans several lines (e.g. it contains `'\n'` characters), you will need to split it before iterating. This is because iterating over a string (rather than a list of strings) will always iterate over characters, rather than words or lines.

Here's some example code:

```
text = "Spam, spam, spam.\Lovely spam!\nWonderful spam!"

lines = text.splitlines() # or use .split("\n") to do it manually

for line in lines:
     do_whatever(line)
```